# In ADFS, how do you remove the "Active Directory" Option in the Sign in page

Tags: adfs, idp

I am running my own Identity Provider with ADFS, and do not want the Active Directory integration with it. When a user logs into the page, I don't want the user to see the "sign in with one of these accounts" page, and instead would like it to just default to the other provider.  I noticed I cannot disable the Active Directory provider in the trusted providers page.

Some of the resources I have found, talk about adjusting the actual login page js, or code file to get it to trick the page into selecting the one I want to default.  I REALLY do not want to do this, and it seems like this should be a simple option somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did eventually figure this out.  The proper way to remove Active Directory from the choice list does NOT involve adjusting js files.  Going into the system and running:

Set-ADFSProperty -EnableLocalAuthenticationTypes $false

This then used the only other identity provider automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is via customising the onload.js.

The whole point of ADFS is to add a federation capability to AD. That's why you cannot easily remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to put both of these 
Set-AdfsProperties -IntranetUseLocalClaimsProvider $false 
Set-AdfsProperties -EnableLocalAuthenticationTypes $false